# ampl can't import random external function

Tags: ampl

I'm using the following code in AMPL

```
load amplgsl.dll;
function gsl_ran_binomial;
```

I get the error:

```
lp.mod, line 6 (offset 138):

Function gsl_ran_binomial is random.
context:  function  >>> gsl_ran_binomial; <<<**
```

Platform: Windows

The approach above works fine with other functions e.g. `gsl_ran_binomial_pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsl_ran_binomial` should be declared with the `random` attribute, because it is a random number generator:

```
function gsl_ran_binomial random;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I was thinking to emulate it using Uniform01 -> Bernoulli -> Binomial, but gsl is more convenient and efficient.